# Magento - how to get more values from addAttributeToFilter?

Tags: magento, addattribute

Hello I hope someone can help me figure out what to do!

I need to get several results from magento. The following code works:

```
private $_orderstatusToFilter = array("processing", "done");

->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => $this->_orderstatusToFilter[0]))
```

this line above shows all the values from one var which is:_orderstatusToFilter = processing. Now I would like to also get all the values where 'status' = (_orderstatusToFilter =) done.

```
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => $this->_orderstatusToFilter[0], 'eq' => $this->_orderstatusToFilter[1]))
```

There are no results if I run the code.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to take out condition like in sample  below

```
$statusCondition = array(
    array(
        'eq' => $this->_orderstatusToFilter[0]
    ),
    array(
        'eq' => $this->_orderstatusToFilter[1]
    )
);

->addAttributeToFilter('status', $statusCondition);
```

Or use **IN** condition instead

```
->addAttributeToFilter('id', array('in' => $_orderstatusToFilter));
```